# Is it possible to save cached items to db on logout using php

Tags: php, xampp

User A log in and add items on cart. When he logs out, the items should be saved somewhere (database or where ever) so that when he logs back in from a different computer, he should see same items he left on his cart.

I think amazon website works like this.

How is this possible if I'm using php and the server is xampp? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. On logout, save it to database and retrieve it on login. Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes you can do this easily. Can you post your code? So we will be able to help you precisely.

Comment: Problem: A lot of the time user don't log out. They just close the browser, the next time they visit they have a new session. Don't place this logic into a logout function, store their actions immediately in the database when they happen.

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet. thanks for all your advice! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing this functionality in the core php?
If it is in some framework or CMS than there will be some module or plugin for this.